# Работа с excel с помощью java стандартными библиотеками

Tags: java, excel

Подскажите варианты работы с экселем с по мощью java без использования внешних библиотек (нет возможности перенести их на комп с джавой). Желательно с примерами.

Comment: Охохохо. Лучше бы, конечно `Apache POI` заюзать. Если вам нужны только данные без всяких "плюшек"  excel - то можете воспользоваться консольным конвертером в CSV(например `ssconvert` в Linux) и потом читать текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Подскажите варианты работы с экселем с по мощью java без использования внешних библиотек

то есть пользуясь только стандартным API Java SE? Ну, как бы путь героя... можно конечно, но это реально путь героя - оценочно несколько тысяч часов жестокого кодирования. Если таки хотите, то путь примерно такой:

1. В последней версии Excel - это по сути зипованный формат XML - [описан здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)
2. То есть читаем, распаковываем ZIP
3. Далее пАрсим XML [очень странного формата](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/understanding-the-open-xml-file-formats)
4. При этом все равно придется использовать либы Microsoft Open XML (не уверен, что они есть под Java)
5. Ну как то так...

Попробуйте все таки заюзать Apache POI.

> нет возможности перенести их на комп с джавой

Ну, неужели нельзя скачать [отсюда](https://poi.apache.org/download.html) либы Apache POI.

> Желательно с примерами.

Пример с Apache POI чтения Excel файла такой:

```
 //открываем файл
 FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xls")); 
 //читаем как книгу Excel
 Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
 //читаем лист с индексом 0
 Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
 Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
 while (iterator.hasNext()) { //цикл по строкам
     Row currentRow = iterator.next();
 }
```

**Update**

Возможен вариант работы через JDBC, но с некоторыми ограничениями:

1) Каждый лист/sheet Excel будет трактоваться как SQL таблица, что означает, что колонки трактуются как поля, а строки как записи, при этом первая строка наименования полей

2) Соединение обычно делается через драйвер JDBC-ODBC

3) Доступ к ячейкам производится через запросы SQL: `select/insert/update/delete`, примерно так

Допустим есть Excel файл с листом Sheet1, примерно такого содержания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда при условия создания соответствующего ODBC datasource к этому файлу, можно сделать так:

```
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:excel","","");
 stmt=conn.createStatement();
 sql="select * from [Sheet1$]"; //читаем лист Sheet1 как таблицу
 rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

 while(rs.next()){
     System.out.println(rs.getString("USERID")+
     " "+ rs.getString("FIRST_NAME")+" "+ 
     rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
 }
```

Comment: Мда, печаль... А с помощью JDBC есть варианты?

Comment: Да, можно см. апдейт ответа